# How display some ImageView in a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

Then, I add 2 ImageView in this Layout:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20);

ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
// Here I give the position of img1

ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
// And here the position and img2

myLayout.addView(img1, params);
myLayout.addView(img2, params);
setContentView(myLayout);
```

And here I have a problem: I want to show and click on the 2 ImageViews, but only the img2 is visible on my screen.

Is there a problem with the z-index or something else?

Comment: Why won't you do this via XML?

Comment: I am using the svg-android library, and apparently it don't allow to use ImageViews via an XML file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using RelativeLayout and same `params` for both ImageView one will be overlapped with the other. So define params for both. `Add rule` to each param for positioning it. And then give `addView()`.

For eg:

```
RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams firstImageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
leftArrowParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

ImageView img2 = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams secImageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rightArrowParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

myLayout.addView(img1, firstImageParams);
myLayout.addView(img2, secImageParams);
setContentView(myLayout);
```